# Mapping EF Foreign key with different names

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the below domain classes:

```
public class Product
{
  public Guid? Id { get; set; }
  public string? Name { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
  public Guid? Id { get; set; }
  public string? Address{ get; set; }
  public Guid? ProductId{ get; set; }
}
```

I am not using navigation properties for setting the foreign key but am doing it as below:

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne<Product>()
               .WithMany()
               .HasForeignKey(c => c.ProductId);
    }
```

My problem when I do the update-database, it says that the field ProductId does not exist. This is because it named as Id in table product but in table order it is named as ProductId. Is there a way to map the foreign key with a different name?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `Product` class

```
public class Product
{
  public Guid? Id { get; set; }
  public string? Name { get; set; }

  public ICollection<Order> Orders {get; set;}
}
```

The relationship will work properly.

Reference: [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)